# jQuery Appending to Parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

Any ideas StackOverflow wizards...

I have added `window.parent.document` to the code, this works without any errors, but the Close Div still seems to be constricted by the container.

Sample can be found here (Click the LIGHTBOX link - bottom right - all styles have been removed): http://demo.squeezedigital.com/barrie-test/iframe-jquery-parent/products.html

Basically, I would like the CLOSE button to sit higher than it currently does.

***Help! :(***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You add a function to the parent, call the parent function whose scope is parent window...
which should work.

Answer (score 0):

"Same origin policy" disallows writing to a different window/iframe document, especially from a different origin (domain). I'm not sure if it is allowed if both pages are from the same domain, but you could try accessing `window.parent` / `window.top`. It may also be rejected by same origin, but give it a try.

Comment: This works as: **$content = $div("body", window.parent.document).append( $close = $div("Close"));** but the div still dissapears when I put bottom margins on it, seems to push it above an invisible barrier.